# How to create a geom_bar with different percentages

Tags: r, ggplot2, percentage, geom-bar, geom-histogram

I want to create a `geometria_bar` with the percentages as followed but the bars always add up to 1, but in reality they show different percentages.
[Here's a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SX7o3.png)

Comment: You are plotting your calculated frequency values to the x-axis, but you most likely expect these to be the heights of the bars (y-axis). Try `aes(x = hotel_type, y = freq, fill = hotel_type)` and use `geom_col()`.

Comment: Please don't paste your code as a picture. [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please post some sample data as copy/pasteable text (`dput(your_data[1:10, ])` is a great way to share a sample. Also please post your code as text so we can copy/paste it and test it and fix it.